# VueJS and dynamic titles

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Trying to use [vue-meta](https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta)

I can't understand how to set title based on XHR response. So far I have:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Model',
        data() {
            return {
                model: [],
            }
        },
        metaInfo: {
            title: 'Default Title',
            titleTemplate: '%s - site slogan'
        },
        methods: {
            getModels() {
                window.axios.get(`/api/${this.$route.params.manufacturer}/${this.$route.params.model}`).then((response) => {
                    this.model = response.data;
                    this.metaInfo.title = response.data.model_name; // THIS NOT WORKING
                });
            }
        },
        watch: {
            $route(to, from) {
                if ( to.name === 'model' ) {
                    this.getModels();
                }
            },
        },
        created() {
            this.getModels();
        }
    }
</script>
```

when I try to set

```
this.metaInfo.title = response.data.model_name;
```

Getting error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined

So this.metaInfo is undefined...

I need my title be based on response from XHR request.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the function form of `metaInfo` and have it get updates from reactive data

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: "Default Title",
            // ...
        };
    },
    metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: this.title,
            // ...
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getModels() {
            window.axios.get("url...").then((response) => {
                this.title = response.data.model_name;
            });
        }
    },
    //  ...
```

Comment: Maybe make sure you're using the latest version of vue-meta and using it correctly. Otherwise, you've found a bug in that package. See https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta#how-do-i-populate-metainfo-from-the-result-of-an-asynchronous-action

Comment: Maybe you right I’m using vuejs 2.5 current latest and vue-meta is for 2.0 didn’t notice that but maybe this is the case...

Comment: The answer remains the same but the updated async documentation is available at https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/faq/async-action.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

I have a root component in my SPA app: `App.vue` with this code in it:

```
export default {
    /**
     * Sets page meta info, such as default and page-specific page titles.
     */
    metaInfo() {
        return {
            titleTemplate(titleChunk) {
                const suffix = "Marvin Rodank's dank site";
                return titleChunk ? `${titleChunk} - ${suffix}` : suffix;
            },
        };
    },

};
```

That sets up my default page title for all pages, and then after that, the answer by **Stephen Thomas** contains the key logic.

For all pages with static page titles, it's easy:

```
metaInfo() {
    return { title: 'List examples' };
},
```

But dynamic page titles were more difficult, but still easy once you realize the page loads in two phases:

- phase 1: browser displays the default page title
- phase 2: page title is updated with the dynamic title

  ```
  metaInfo() {
      return {
          title: this.example.name,
      };
  },
  ```

In the dynamic title example there, my child component fetches the object `this.example` from an API endpoint, so it is important to note that `this.$metaInfo().title` updates itself when `this.example` is populated.

You could test it with code such as this:

```
  metaInfo() {
      return {
          title: this.example.name,
      };
  },

  mounted() {
      const obj = {
          name: 'Sally',
          age: 1337,
      };

      this.example = obj;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you call `this.metaInfo.title = response.data.model_name;` inside a method on the vue instance. The problem I see is that you should put the metaInfo object inside the return object from data(). Like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    model: [],
      metaInfo: {
        title: 'Default Title',
        titleTemplate: '%s - site slogan'
     },
  };
},
```

Comment: No, in this case, even default title will not set. The problem is I can't set my custom title.